# How do I write this in a query in Elastic?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have a need to execute a query similar to

*select from INDEX where **field1** IN ('a','b','c') AND **field2** IN ('d', 'e', 'f') AND **field3** IN ('g', 'h', 'i')*

I am using Elastic from node.js to perform this query. I already have the index and mappings created.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out I wrote the query as:

```
query: {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {"term": {"field1": "a"}},
                                    {"term": {"field1": "b"}}
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {"term": {"field2": "d"}},
                                    {"term": {"state": "e"}}
                                ]
                            }
                        }, //........
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I need to figure out how to generate this query dynamically next.

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler way would be using a [`terms` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "field1": [ "a", "b", "c" ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "field2": [ "d", "e", "f" ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "field3": [ "g", "h", "i" ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can read from the official docs, a `terms` query provides a simpler syntax instead several `term` inside a `bool/should` query.